# AutoSuggest running problem

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, autosuggest

> **This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
<h:head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="themes/bluesky/skin.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>

<center>
<p:panel header="Login Form" style="width: 350;">
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2">
<h:outputLabel for="#{UserManagedBean.username}" value="UserName"/>
<h:inputText value="#{UserManagedBean.username}" label="UserName"/>
<h:outputLabel for="#{UserManagedBean.password}" value="Password"/>
<h:inputSecret value="#{UserManagedBean.password}"/>
<h:commandButton type="submit" value="Login" action="#{UserManagedBean.login}"/>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</p:panel>
<div>
<h:messages/>
</div>
</center>
</h:body>
</html>
```

What could be the possible problem here? I really don't know.

Answer (score 1):

> *This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.*

This is a typical MSIE warning message whenever you request a X(HT)ML file which does not have a XSL stylesheet (which is basically like CSS for HTML).

That you're getting this on a Facelet page can only mean that the request URL did not match the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` as definited in your webapp's `web.xml`. In other words, the `FacesServlet` has never got any chance to run, parse that Facelet file and do all the JSF works to generate a bunch of HTML so that the webbrowser has something sensible to work with.

There are 2 solutions for this problem:

- Fix your request URL (the one in browser address bar) to match the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` in `web.xml`. If it is for example `<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>`, then you need to replace `.xhtml` extension in URL by `.jsf`.
- Change the URL pattern of your `FacesServlet` to `<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>`. This way you do not need to worry about accidently seeing XHTML source anymore.

Please note that this all has **nothing** to do with "autosuggest problem". Work yourself through some basic JSF tutorials first. [Our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) has some good links.

Oh, before I forgot, the `<center>` element is *deprecated* since HTML4 in 1998. Do not use it. Use CSS `margin: 0 auto;`. Try to avoid reading tutorials/books older than 2 years.